# C++: Inheritance and Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have two structs:

```
template <typename T>
struct Odp
{
    T m_t;

    T operator=(const T rhs)
    {
        return m_t = rhs;
    }
};

struct Ftw : public Odp<int>
{
    bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs)
    {
        return m_t == rhs.m_t;
    } 
};
```

I would like the following to compile:

```
int main()
{
    Odp<int> odp;
    odp = 2;

    Ftw f;
    f = 2; // C2679: no operator could be found
}
```

Is there any way to make this work, or must I define the operator in `Ftw` as well?

Comment: Usually `operator = ` takes const reference parameter... It would be better to change `T operator=(const T rhs)` to `T operator=(const T& rhs)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler usually creates an `operator=` for you (unless you provide one), and this `operator=` hides the inherited one. You can overrule this by using-declaration:

```
struct Ftw : public Odp<int>
{
    using Odp<int>::operator=;
    bool operator==(const Ftw& rhs)
    {
        return m_t == rhs.m_t;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that.