# virtual assignment

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble understanding this issue.

I have a class:

```
class StringProperty { //snipped...
protected:
    std::string s;
public:
    virtual StringProperty& operator= (const std::string &x) {
        s = x;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual StringProperty& foo(const std::string &x) {
        s = x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This class (which have more methods and were snipped for simplicity) should act as a string.

When I derive from it:

```
class Test : public StringProperty { };
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Test x;
x = "test";
```

However, this fails miserably (does not compile):

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘x = "test"’
```

Nonetheless, if I use

```
x.foo("test");
```

It works.
I'm interested in understanding why it fails, since for me both functions are identical.

Thanks.

Comment: return type of `StringProperty& operator=(...)` is not compatible with the LHS' type in `x = "test";`

Comment: @thekashyap: The operator can return any type, or nothing. It's only a convention to return `*this` to allow chaining.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410688/c-inheritance-and-operator-overloading

Comment: @jjlin: Please elaborate why you think this is a valid duplicate. The one you link to deals with inheritance and operator hiding/resurfacing, while this here does not. How are they related?

Comment: If you read the other question, it's pretty self-evident. It's asking why operator= isn't visible in the subclass, and the answer there is the same as here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Test` class contains an implicitly-declared copy-assignment operator (and also a default constructor, copy constructor and destructor). This hides the one in the base class. In order for that to be considered as an overload, you have to make it accessible in the derived class:

```
class Test : public StringProperty {
public:
    using StringProperty::operator=;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't realized that the default methods were hiding the base.

Comment: Except that the base class `operator=` doesn't have the correct semantics, and will result in slicing (and possibly objects which don't respect the class invariants of the derived class).  All the `using` does is get the code through the compiler; it still won't behave in a reasonable manner.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't think there's any slicing here; assignment from a string will use the base-class version (modifying `s`), and assignment from something convertible to `Test` will use the implicit operator. I'm fairly sure the `using` doesn't inhibit the implicit one (and a quick test seems to confirm that), but please correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: How/why does this work? How can compiler do implicit downcasting from `StringProperty` (base) to `Test` (derived) when compiling `Test x; x = "test";` ?

Comment: The problem will occur when you start assigning through pointers.  What does it mean to assign a `StringProperty` to a `Test`, or vice versa?  You can't change the type of the existing object.

Comment: @thekashyap: There's no downcasting involved - that code just calls the assignment operator defined in the base class, exactly as `x.foo("test")` would call the function defined in the base class.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Who said anything about assigning `StringProperty` to `Test`, or changing types? The question is about making all the subclasses of `StringProperty` assignable from `std::string`.

Comment: Hmm.. I get it now.. what confused me is the fact that `x` is of type `Test` and return type of `operator=` is `StringProperty`..

Answer (score 3):

That's classic.

`operator=` is one of the special methods the compiler creates for you if you don't. Consequently, this automatically created method hides the inherited method.

You can solve it by adding

```
using StringProperty::operator=;
```

line to class Test.

Answer (score 1):

Copy assignment and copy constructors are something that would be generated for your Test class by default.

Others already beat me to the solution with detailed explanations, so I'm going to focus on something else with a rant.

I've seen hierarchical designs like this get problematic real fast. I even worked with a senior developer designing an architecture who couldn't even get a basic mathematical vector library correct because he thought he could create a vector base class, derive from it, add more members to a subclass, and reuse things like copying semantics from the base class (including operator=). Suffice to say, he encountered issues like slicing very quickly. I told him to stop trying to use inheritance so much in this 'extend' fashion (subclasses modeling things that seem more like superclasses). Issues like this add a lot of fuel to the fire for those claiming that C++ is a terrible language (ex: Linus Torvalds), since a lot of people make object-oriented design mistakes using it particularly when inheritance is involved (the other main source, I'd argue, as being monolithic class designs).

The very concept of assignment provided to subclasses through a base class breaks polymorphism. Imagine a Dog and Cat inherit from Mammal which provides copy semantics to both. What happens when we copy a Dog to a Cat? Say we call some function which accepts Mammal& and assigns Cat to it, but we passed in a reference to a Dog. What's supposed to happen? It makes no logical sense. Yet the compiler would allow this if Dog and Cat are both using the copy functions or operators from Mammal.

For this reason, I strongly recommend you design your base classes generally to be noncopyable and look into things like a virtual clone method (Prototype Pattern) to avoid these kinds of designs all together. Base classes generally need to be designed appropriately and carefully to be base classes with polymorphism in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Assignment and polymorphism do not work well together.  The symptom 
you're seeing is easy to fix: the compiler provided assignment operator
in your derived class hides any assignment operators in the base class.
So you'll have to provide an implementation of it.  The problem remains,
however, that you can't really provide any reasonable semantics for it:

```
Base* p1 = new Derived;
Base* p2 = new Base;
*p2 = *p1;
```

What should happen at the last line?  I would expect that after, `*p1 ==
*p2`, for some appropriate definition of equality.  But part of the
“value” of `*p1` is that it has the dynamic type `Derived`. 
Which you cannot do, since you cannot change the type of an object once
it has been constructed.

(It is possible to make value types which behave polymorphically, and
yet support assignment, by means of some variant of the letter-envelope
idiom.  It's a lot of work, typically very slow, and not usually worth
it.)

Comment: Could you explain what this has to do with polymorphically assigning from a string? I'm finding it hard to see the connection with the question.

Comment: I was talking about assignment in general.  It's true that the special case he's interested in probably isn't affected by the problem---it's more a problem for copy assignment.